# How do you mock lodash debounce.cancel with jest?

Tags: mocking, jestjs, lodash, debouncing

Looking for some recommendations on how to mock the `.cancel` method in a debounce from lodash.

I have a function that is calling `debounce` and then later utilizing the returned debounce value to call `debouncedThing.cancel()`.

I am able to mock `debounce` just fine in my tests except for when my function is called `.cancel()`.

At the top of my unit tests I am currently doing:

`jest.mock('lodash/debounce', () => fn => fn));`

The above mock has worked fine except for in the place where I am calling `debouncedThing.cancel()`. In those test, I get an error that `debouncedThing.cancel()` is not a function.

Psuedo code of where I am using debounce looks like this:

```
const debouncedThing = debounce(
  (myFunc, data) => myFunc(data),
  DEBOUNCE_DELAY_TIME,
);

const otherFunc = () => {
 /* omitted */
 debouncedThing.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You just need to add the `cancel` function to `fn`:

```js
jest.mock('lodash/debounce', () => fn => {
  fn.cancel = jest.fn();
  return fn;
});
```

Example of it in use:

```js
const debounce = require('lodash/debounce');

test('debouncedThing', () => {
  const thing = jest.fn();
  const debouncedThing = debounce(thing, 1000);

  debouncedThing('an arg');
  expect(thing).toHaveBeenCalledWith('an arg');  // Success!

  debouncedThing.cancel();  // no error
  expect(debouncedThing.cancel).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
});
```

Comment: ...also, depending on your code and what you are trying to test you might be able to avoid needing to mock `debounce` by using [Timer Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks.html) instead.